# How to auto load Facebook ads SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to load Facebook ads SDK class via composer. i am going to share what i have done and where i stuck.

Sdk patch

```
/system/services/facebook/FacebookAds/
```

Where i am loading class

```
/facebook.php
```

what files are exits in SDK root

[image]

Here is my `facebook.php` code.basically i am following to official facebook Github documentation.

```
        use FacebookAds\Api;

        // Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object
        Api::init("*********", "************", "***************");

        // The Api object is now available trough singleton
        $api = Api::instance();
```

I am gating `Fatal error: Class 'FacebookAds\Api' not found` Error. simple is what class i am hitting this actually not exits where my code finding. basically i am confusing about how composer actually work. i am using composer first time. Kindly clear me with any example using my patch reference and explain me how actually composer auto load all class files or is there any manual way to done this. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need PSR-4 to auload

The classes within the Facebook Ads SDK are designed to be included using an autoloader compliant with the PSR-4. If you are using Composer to include dependencies, you will find an implementation available within the vendor folder. This guide assumes you are using this autoloader.

```
<?php
define('VENDOR_DIR', '/path/to/sdk/'); // Path to the Vendor directory 
$loader = include VENDOR_DIR.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

after that

you can call it

use FacebookAds\Api;

// Set the default application to be used with this session and register an instance of the Api object

```
Api::init('<APP_ID>', '<APP_SECRET>', '<ACCESS_TOKEN>');
```

// The instace is now retrivable

```
$api = Api::instance();
```